# Как забиндить данные в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Проблема такая, у меня есть класс

```
internal class Student
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public int Course { get; set; }
    public List<Exam> Exams { get; set; }

    public Student(string fullname, string group, int course)
    {
        FullName = fullname;
        Group = group;
        Course = course;
    }
}

internal class Exam
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public Exam(string name, string decr)
    {
        Name = name;
        Description = decr;
    }
}
```

И `DataGrid`, который прибинден к этому коллекции этих классов

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="DGStudents" Margin="10" IsReadOnly="True" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=studends}">
        
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Студент" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=FullName}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Группа" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=Group}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Курс" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=Course}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                <Grid>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.25*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.75*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Exams}"
                              DisplayMemberPath="Name">
                    </ComboBox>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
```

Коллекция:

```
 public ObservableCollection<Student> studends { get; set; }
        = new ObservableCollection<Student>()
            {
                new Student("Ivan Petrov", "21-KB-PR2", 2) 
                    {Exams = new List<Exam>()
                        { 
                        new Exam("Math", "Perfect"),
                        new Exam("OOP", "Good"),
                        new Exam("TRPO", "Bad")
                    }
            }
        };
```

Вопрос таков я хочу чтобы после выбора предмета в `ComboBox` `TextBlock` менял свое значение на значение `Description`, который находится в классе `Exam`, а тот в классе `Student`.

Пытался сделать это все через `SelectedItem`:

```
private static Exam _selected_item;

    public static Exam SelectedItem
    {
        get => _selected_item;
        set => OnPropertyChanged();
    }
```

Но у меня биндинг просто не видит это свойство.

Comment: `static` уберите и увидит

Comment: Это сделал, спасибо за помощь, появился второй, как забиндить `TextBlock` если у меня в `Path` отображаются свойства списка `students`

Comment: также с `SelectedItem`